# How to calculate actual values from Excel like 1.30389E+15 in PHP?

Tags: php, excel, csv

I see there are values displayed in Excel like - 1.30389E+15
Its original value is 1303890710980110

Does anyone have idea about how to convert this back to original value in PHP?

I tried searching it, but never came out with success. I don't know at this point of time what exactly this is called so that I can search the exact term.

Comment: You should try to set the cell type to "number", since the default is "general"

Comment: This just means the same as `1.30389 * 10^15` but this will not give you the exact same number.

Comment: You cannot convert it back in PHP once the numbers get autoconverted (and rounded (**!**)) to scientific notation by the spreadsheet application.

Answer (score 3):

The size of [PHP_INT_MAX](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.constants.php#constant.php-int-max) depends on the architecture of your PHP interpreter:

- In 32-bit PHP it's 2,147,483,647
- In 64-bit PHP it's 9,223,372,036,854,775,807

Comparing the involved figures:

```
    1,303,890,710,980,110 -> Excel value
            2,147,483,647 -> 32-bit max value
9,223,372,036,854,775,807 -> 64-bit max value
```

... the conclusion is that:

- If you need a portable solution (or your server is 32-bit) you must handle it as string. There's just no other way. If you happen to need maths you'll also need an arbitrary precision library like [GMP](http://php.net/gmp) or [BCMath](http://php.net/bcmath).
- Otherwise, you shouldn't need to do anything special as long as all numbers are known to fit into the 64-bit range.

The vague part in your question is how numbers travel from Microsoft Excel to your PHP script. I presume you're using a third-party library, ODBC or both. If they're already "broken" (i.e. converted to floating point) when they reach you, there's nothing you can do to get the lost precision back.

Another question you should ask yourself is whether you have real numbers or they're mere alphanumeric codes.

Comment: This is very interesting to note. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

As you put in your question, the spreadsheet application converted your data `1303890710980110` into `1.30389E+15` while obviously lowering the precision ten times. Nothing can be done afterwards in PHP in order to fix the precision back. The steps have to be done ***before*** exporting the data from the spreadsheet app.

You have to change the format of the cells holding these numbers in the spreadsheet application in order to be able to process it later with the same precision.

You have to:

- **change the cell format** to `Number` (as [@Davide Effe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6301009/davide-effe) suggests)
- **stretch the cell width** wide enough for the number (in a normal form) to fit in (important: spreadsheet applications autoconvert
  these while lowering precision into the scientific notation because
  it needs less width to fit)

[image]

Once that's done, the exported data should be in a correct format and the precision intact.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [number_format](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php) to achieve the conversion.

`echo number_format(1.30389E+15);`

Output: `1,303,890,000,000,000`

The output posted above doesn't match your original value `1303890710980110` but that's how you would convert scientific notation.

In order to get the original value you mentioned, the notation would look like this `1.30389071098011E+15`.

To check simply run: `echo number_format(1.30389071098011E+15);`

This would give you `1,303,890,710,980,110`, the original value.

Comment: Maybe it doesn't match because excel did something to change your original value? If you move the decimal point 15 places as the E+15 indicates you will get the value I got from (1.30389E+15).